# How to use % in the path of the view?

Tags: views, 8

I created a view that displays my shop (mathieu) in a table. I want to display this view with the following path :

/shop/mathieu/shop

I have to do this for several shops. How to use% in the path of the view ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use contextual filters, you should use paths like store/%/boutique, where % is the value passed to the contextual filter.

If you have a contextual filter based on a node id, the path could be store/123/boutique, where "123" is a nid.